# ZF2 define service to send email

Tags: email, service, zend-framework2

I am sending emails from my ZF2 application. I want to create it as a service so that I can use it from any module and any controller.

I have the code to send the emails, need guidance to create service.

```
protected function sendEMail($msgSubj,$msgText, $fromEmail, $toEmail) {
    $mail = new Mail\Message();
    $mail->setFrom($fromEmail, $fromEmail);
    $mail->addTo($toEmail, $toEmail);
    $mail->setSubject($msgSubj);
    $mail->setBody($msgText);
    $transport = new Mail\Transport\Sendmail();
    $transport->send($mail);
    return true;
}
```

I am currently having this function defined in one of the controllers to send the email. However, my application is evolving and I need to send application from multiple modules and multiple controllers within modules. 
I understand that this will be easier if I define sending email as a service and call it as required. I have read the documentation and it is considerably heavy. I am looking for examples where someone has done something similar.
Thanks in advance for your time.

2nd Edit on 2014-05-11
I have done the following

1> created a new service class SendEmail with the following code

```
namespace Application\Service;


class SendEmail {

    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    protected function sendEMail($msgSubj,$msgText, $fromEmail, $toEmail) {
        $mail = new \Zend\Mail\Message();
        $mail->setFrom($fromEmail, $fromEmail);
        $mail->addTo($toEmail, $toEmail);
        $mail->setSubject($msgSubj);
        $mail->setBody($msgText);
        $transport = new \Zend\Mail\Transport\Sendmail();
        $transport->send($mail);
        return true;
    }

}
```

2> defined an entry in module.config.php for the Application Module
under "service_manager" -> "factories"

```
'SendEmail' => 'Application\Service\SendEmail',
```

3> defined the function in IndexController

```
public function getSendEmail( ) {
    if ( !$this->sendEmail ) {
        $this->sendEmail = $this->getServiceLocator( )->get( 'SendEmail' );
    }
    return $this->sendEmail;
}
```

4> at the place where I want to send the email I have the following code

```
$sendEmail = $this->getSendEmail( );
$sendEmail->sendEMail("subject of email","email body message", "from@email.com", "to@email.com");
```

5> I added Application\Service\SendEmail to the list of invokables

I am getting the following error

```
Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotCreatedException
File:
/var/www/zf2/dwam/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:1036
Message:
While attempting to create sendemail(alias: SendEmail) an invalid factory was registered for this instance type.
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/zf2/dwam/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php(612): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createFromFactory('sendemail', 'SendEmail')
#1 /var/www/zf2/dwam/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php(572): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate('SendEmail', 'sendemail')
#2 /var/www/zf2/dwam/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php(504): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->create(Array)
#3 /var/www/zf2/dwam/module/UserAdmin/src/UserAdmin/Controller/IndexController.php(123): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('SendEmail')
#4 /var/www/zf2/dwam/module/UserAdmin/src/UserAdmin/Controller/IndexController.php(77): UserAdmin\Controller\IndexController->getSendEmail()
#5 /var/www/zf2/dwam/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/AbstractActionController.php(83): UserAdmin\Controller\IndexController->userLoginAction()
#6 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#7 /var/www/zf2/dwam/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#8 /var/www/zf2/dwam/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#9 /var/www/zf2/dwam/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/AbstractController.php(117): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#10 /var/www/zf2/dwam/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/DispatchListener.php(114): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#11 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#12 /var/www/zf2/dwam/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#13 /var/www/zf2/dwam/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#14 /var/www/zf2/dwam/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Application.php(316): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#15 /var/www/zf2/dwam/public/index.php(17): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#16 {main}
```

Basically the service has not been created; what am I missing; What more needs to be done.

Edit on 2014-05-12 Found the solution; not sure if this is the best way though!!!

I would request the group of AlexP, nikoshr, EdChum, Eight-Bit Guru, Tad Donaghe to remove the hold so that I can publish the solution.

Comment: Read the [the documentation](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.service-manager.intro.html)?

Comment: I have updated the question more clearly

Comment: You could add that class to the "factories" array that is returned in the getServiceConfig() method in your Module.php file. Then in your controller you would get that class by using the service locator, then call the sendEMail() method accordingly from the object returned by the SL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution and I am posting the code that work well for me; Do comment on any other improvements that can be made.

1> created a new service class `SendEmail` with the following code
namespace `Application\Service`;

```
class SendEmail {

    public function sendEMail($msgSubj,$msgText, $fromEmail, $toEmail) {
        $mail = new \Zend\Mail\Message();
        $mail->setFrom($fromEmail, $fromEmail);
        $mail->addTo($toEmail, $toEmail);
        $mail->setSubject($msgSubj);
        $mail->setBody($msgText);
        $transport = new \Zend\Mail\Transport\Sendmail();
        $transport->send($mail);
        return true;
    }

}
```

2> defined in `module.php` for the Application Module create the function `getServiceConfig()`

```
'factories' => array (
    'SendEmail' => function ( $sm ) {
        return new \Application\Service\SendEmail( );
    },
),
```

3> defined the function in `IndexController`

```
public function getSendEmail( ) {
    if ( !$this->sendEmail ) {
        $this->sendEmail = $this->getServiceLocator( )->get( 'SendEmail' );
    }
    return $this->sendEmail;
}
```

4> at the place where I want to send the email I have the following code

```
$sendEmail = $this->getSendEmail( );
$sendEmail->sendEMail("subject of email","email body message", "from@email.com", "to@email.com");
```

Comment: no need for a factory here, since it only returns an instance.

use 'invokable' instead.

Comment: are you suggesting me to define \Application\Service\SendEmail() as an invokable. ok, it could be a good idea